# Allow some html tags

Tags: php, html, tags, strip-tags

I need to allow certain html tags (br,p and strong) and I have encountered this code.

```
 (strip_tags($this->parent->content[$i]['text']), $this->parent->config, 'portal_mode_grid_news_text_length', '&hellip;').'</p>';
```

All I need is to allow those tags I have stated previously, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: strip_tags, 2nd paramater

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `strip_tags`](https://php.net/strip_tags), it shows that the second parameter is "allowed tags", so an example of how to allow br, p and strong is like so:

```
$string = "Hello<br>";
echo strip_tags($string, "<br><br/><p><strong>");
```

> Adding br and br/ together allows both types of line break as opposed to just one.

```
(strip_tags($this->parent->content[$i]['text'], "<br><br/><p><strong>"), $this->parent->config, 'portal_mode_grid_news_text_length', '&hellip;').'</p>';
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, that's what first came up when I was searching but I don't get how I should include it in the code I pasted in my question :/, in which part and how should I write it. I'm a total noob so all that code just got me complete lost. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: @cdp.fl - It's the same as in the documentation - `strip_tags($input, '<br><br/>');` in your example it would be something like `strip_tags($this->parent->content[$i]['text'],'<br><br/><p><strong>')` -- add `,'<br><br/><p><strong>'` inside strip_tags.

Comment: As ManSam said. I copied your code and edited it accordingly so you can see how to apply it to your code :).

Comment: Thanks a lot! ChrisEvans and MamSam!! :)

Comment: Update : Since PHP 5.3.4 and later, self-closing XHTML tags are ignored and only non-self-closing tags should be used in allowable_tags. So you can use '<br>' instead of '<br><br/>'.